# D3 can not get this.parentNode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

i have started with d3, on this moment i tray to edit a given script to meed the new requirments. I tray to reach a variabel but i can not access it. can someone help me out?

The problem is on line 5, i can not get "this.parentNode" but i need it.

Can someone point me in the right drection?

Thanks for your time

Greathings

```
function lines(x, yl, yr, n, svgElement, colors, Line) {
    Line = Line || d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.time) + x.bandwidth() /2; })
        .y(function(d) {
            if(parseInt(d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("data-index")) !== scope.dataset.labels.indexOf(scope.rightas) && scope.rightas !== null) {
                return yl(d.y); 
            }
            return yr(d.y);
        });

    svgElement.selectAll('.line')
        .data(function(d){ return [d]; })
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", Line)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("fill", "none" )
        .style("stroke", function(d, i, j) {
            return d3.rgb(colors[d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("data-index")]).darker();
        })
        .style("stroke-width", "2")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get `this` DOM element from inside the line generator (with or without Angular). The line generator has no access to the element you're appending using it.

The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#line) is clear about that:

> When a line is generated, the x accessor will be invoked for each defined element in the **input data array**, being passed the element d, the index i, and the array data as three arguments. (emphasis mine)

The same, obviously, goes for the `y` accessor. So, as you can see, only the data is passed.

Therefore, `this` in this case will be simply the [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), and there is no `parentNode` here.

Look at this demo (as the stack snippet takes a long time to console.log the window object, I'm using only `this.name`):

```js
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    console.log(this.name);
    return d;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

line([1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, i understand it. Is it possible to send the "this.parentNode).attr("data-index")" value to the line generator?

I need that value

Comment: You can do it in your line selection.

Comment: do you meen ==>  .attr("d", d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("data-index"))?

Comment: No. This question has been already answered and editing it is not a valid option. Therefore, whatever you're trying to do, please post a *new* question, explaining your problem and the desired output.